# php split a number with 2 part, Single digit and the rest

Tags: php, split, numbers

Is there any good way to split a number with 2 part, Single digit and the rest?

```
123456 => 12345   6
789 => 78  9
12357 =? 1235 7
```

My idea is first use `strlen()` to get number lenght then use `substr()` to get `Single digit` and `the rest`.

Anyone have better idae? more easy way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input originally is a number, then why not:

```
$num = 123456;
echo floor($num / 10); //first part
echo $num % 10;        // second part
```

Answer (score 0):

Try only

```
substr($yourStringorNumber,-1)
```

to get the last sign/digit.
You can get the other part with

```
substr($yourStringorNumber,0,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get both sections, I would use the following strlen calls.

```
$first  = substr($string, 0, -1);
$second = substr($string, -1);
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean strlen? strlen only expects one parameter. I think you mean substr?

Comment: `substr`! My bad! Far too early :)